# Lucy likes Mystery

Tags: logical-deduction, knowledge

> **Lucy likes Jaipur but not Kerala**
>
> **Lucy likes Corbett National Park but not Periyar National Park**
>
> **Lucy likes Assam but not Telangana**

What does Lucy like, and why? What doesn't she like and why not?

I will add hints tomorrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Lucy also likes Kashmir but not Kanyakumari. Because:

> All the places that Lucy likes are located in Northern half of India while the places that she doesn't like are in the southern half.
> [**Map**](https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Assam/Jim+Corbett+National+Park,+Nainital+District,+Ramnagar,+Uttarakhand+244715/Jaipur,+Rajasthan/Telangana/Periyar+National+Park,+Kerala/Kerala/@19.292365,75.1296657,5z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m38!4m37!1m5!1m1!1s0x374516c94c312d63:0xd11a73bb736719fb!2m2!1d92.9375739!2d26.2006043!1m5!1m1!1s0x390a24ffffffffff:0x3017b72d3d253fd7!2m2!1d78.7746603!2d29.5300138!1m5!1m1!1s0x396c4adf4c57e281:0xce1c63a0cf22e09!2m2!1d75.7872709!2d26.9124336!1m5!1m1!1s0x3a3350db9429ed43:0x63ef7ba741594059!2m2!1d79.0192997!2d18.1124372!1m5!1m1!1s0x3b06f7f28a088c89:0x1f8406b9a08dc67b!2m2!1d77.2368474!2d9.462155!1m5!1m1!1s0x3b0812ffd49cf55b:0x64bd90fbed387c99!2m2!1d76.2710833!2d10.8505159!3e0)